# Databricks consuming rest api

Tags: scala, api, apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm new to Azure Databricks and Scala, i'm trying to consume HTTP REST API that's returning JSON, i went around the databricks docs but i don't see any Datasource that would work with rest api.Is there any library or tutorial on how to work with rest api in databricks. If i make multiple api calls (cause of pagination) it would be nice to get it done in parallel way (spark way).

I would be glad if you guys could point me if there is a Databricks or Spark way to consume REST API as i was shocked that there's no information in docs about api datasource.

Comment: Isn't this what you want:
https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/index.html  ?

Comment: nope i don't want to consume databricks rest api but external api, the link you sent is describing api that databricks has but i wanna consume external api and create job to import data once hour into databricks database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is A `Simple` Implementation.

Basic Idea is `spark.read.json` can read an `RDD`.

So, just create an `RDD` from `GET` call and then read it as **regular** dataframe.

```
%spark
def get(url: String) = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

val myUrl = "https://<abc>/api/v1/<xyz>"

val result = get(myUrl)

val jsonResponseStrip = result.toString().stripLineEnd 

val jsonRdd = sc.parallelize(jsonResponseStrip :: Nil)

val jsonDf = spark.read.json(jsonRdd)
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like what you want, is to import into scala a library for making HTTP requests.  I suggest the HTTP instead of a higher level REST interface, because the pagination may be handled in the REST library and may or may not support parallelism.
Managing with the lower level HTTP lets you de-couple pagination.  Then you can use the parallelism mechanism of your choice.

There are a number of libraries out there, but recommending a specific one is out of scope.

If you do not want to import a library, you could have your scala notebook call upon another notebook running a language which has HTTP included in the standard library.  This notebook would then return the data to your scala notebook.